# Filter list of objects by id list in MongoTemplate aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I have a part of operation like below

```
 mongoTemplate.aggregate(
        newAggregation(unwind("catalogItems"),
            group("catalogItems._id").addToSet("catalogItems.modifierId").as("modIds").addToSet(
                new BasicDBObject("_id", "$recipe._id").append("name", "$recipe.name")
                    .append("menuId", "$recipe.menuId").append("status", "$recipe.status")
                    .append("modifierList",
        new BasicDBObject("modifiers", new BasicDBObject("id", new BasicDBObject("$in", "$modIds")))))
                .as("recipeList")),
        "table", Ingredient.class).getMappedResults();
```

Here what I'm trying to do is assign modifiers that contains the ids in $modIds.

```
modifierList - the property I'm going to assign the result with filtered modifiers
modifiers - input list that contains all elements
$modIds - modifier ids got by previous projection
```

When I try this, I get following error

```
Expression $in takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.' on server
```

I think my syntax is not ok. But I can't find a working example with my requirement. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: You need to show use complete query. Seems like you want search `$in` document's field? In that case, you should use [Operator expresion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/#exp._S_in)

Comment: I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    unwind("catalogItems"), 
    match(Criteria.where("catalogItems.name").regex("^" + name, "i")),
    group("catalogItems._id", "catalogItems.name","catalogItems.status")
        .addToSet("catalogItems.modifierId").as("modIds")
        .addToSet(new Document("_id", new Document("$toString","$recipe._id"))
                .append("name", "$recipe.name")
                .append("menuId", "$recipe.menuId")
                .append("modifiers","$modifiers")).as("recipeList"), 
    project()
        .and("_id._id").as("_id")
        .and("_id.name").as("name")
        .and("_id.status").as("status")
        .and(op -> new Document("$map", 
                new Document("input", "$recipeList")
                    .append("as", "recipe")
                    .append("in", new Document("id","$$recipe._id")
                            .append("name", "$$recipe.name")
                            .append("status", "$$recipe.status")
                            .append("menuId", "null")
                            .append("modifiers", new Document("$map", 
                                new Document("input", new Document("$filter", 
                                    new Document("input", "$$recipe.modifiers")
                                        .append("as", "modif")
                                        .append("cond", new Document("$in", Arrays.asList("$$modif._id", "$modIds"))))
                                    ).append("as", "mod")
                                .append("in", new Document("id", "$$mod._id")
                                        .append("recipeId", "$$mod.recipeId")
                                        .append("displayName", "$$mod.displayName")
                                        .append("status", "$$mod.status"))))
                                ))).as("recipeList"));

mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "table", Ingredient.class).getMappedResults();
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o4eJ6WtGYJV)

Comment: Now I get this error `$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing' on server`

Comment: @Sandeepa That means you have empty `catalogItems` array. Share a sample data, I will fix the query

Comment: since the sample data is too long. I have shared my queries and sample data in a chat with you in here. So that you will get an clear idea. Thank you very much you for your help :)

Comment: @Sandeepa check my answer again